# How to achieve NAS to NAS rsync for offsite backup?

Tags: nas, rsync

I'm interested in a home NAS solution that would look like this:

- local NAS box for home backups
- remote NAS box (at my parents) as an offsite copy
- periodic `rsync` over the internet from "local" to "remote" for offsite copy

I see that QNAP and Synology run linux implementations.. so want to confirm that I can `rsync` between two NAS boxes.

I know I could build/run two linux boxes but am looking for low cost/low effort in getting it up and running.

Comment: I would be surprised if the QNAP and Synology systems didn't support `rsync`. If you were to build your own NAS (which can be [much cheaper](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/09/14/building-a-nas-server-2/) than off the shelf boxes), then [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) has support for `rsync`.

Comment: QNAP certainly does as we rsync to/from them at work, but just watch out (in general) for NASs based on low-power CPUs (such as the single core Atoms) with not a lot of RAM as rsync is quite processor/RAM intensive - backing up *part* of our QNAP (about 2TB) has rsync soak up around 10GB RAM as it caches the file structure on the target server (a quad core box with 16GB RAM).